# Make variables available inside of a function.(PHP)

Tags: php, function, variables

Im building an application to track certain information about the clients we deal with like *name/date/hrs worked/phone number* etc. This information is stored in a db. Because we have different departments like SEO/WEB/Sales etc, and different people within these teams, the app provides different ways to filter the information depending on the filter button pressed.

When someone presses a "filter button", in this example, lets say they pressed the "view by department" button, it takes them to actual hardcoded pages. 
As an example:

```
viewSeoAccs.php

viewWebAccs.php

ViewSalesAccs.php
```

And in these pages i have queries which pull the information based on the filter pressed but the html is the same. Now here comes the problem.

I have many different pages(based on filters) and every time there is an edit to be made to the html, i have to go into EVERY PHP page to implement the changes.

What i want to do is create a function that spits out the html for me. I have gotten about half way and i know the problem, just cant seem to find a solution.

Here is some code.

In my functions.php file, i have a function called "htmlBlockTEST" that has this code.

```
   EXAMPLE: (code chopped for easy reading)
    <?php
        function htmlBlockTEST(){

                echo '' ?>


    <h2 class="accName fl"><?php echo $row['company_name']; ?></h2>
    <div class="<?php echo $row['acc_risk']; ?>"> Risk Level. </div>


    //ALOT MORE CODE goes here lol.

    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

This is in the header and bought in via "include_once('functions.php').
Under this, i have specific variables that pull in the queried data. (example below)

```
$pullAllAccounts = "SELECT * FROM tlm_accounts ORDER BY company_name ASC;";
$pullAllAccountsDoIt = mysqli_query($c2d, $pullAllAccounts) or die ("could not pull WEB team data" . mysqli_error($c2d));
?>
```

now i loop through the db and display the information like so:

```
<?php

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pullAllAccountsDoIt)){
$compName = $row['company_name'];


?>


<?php htmlBlockTEST(); ?>

<?php 

    }

?>
```

In this code directly above, where the function call "htmlBlockTEST" is, is where the problem is. Since The variables which hold the queries are outside the function, I'm assuming that they aren't being passed into the function. I dont want to put them inside the function because the HTML is the same throughout all the pages, but not ALL data.

I need the variables that hold for example `$row['company_name']` to be also available inside the function so that it doesn't throw "undefined variable" errors.

How can i make this happen? What is the best way to get these variables in the while loop(or otherwise) to be available inside the function???

PS, ive google and found things like $GLOBALS['x'] etc but from what ive read, its not the best way or easiers and overall im confused on how to even use it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: As param maybe? htmlBlockTEST($compName);

Comment: yeah i tried that too and it didnt work.

Comment: As Reza said, htmlBlockTEST() needs to be in while loop also :) Other option is in the realm of reactive programing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pullAllAccountsDoIt)){
    htmlBlockTEST($row);
}
```

Option 2:

```
global $row;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($pullAllAccountsDoIt)){
    $compName = $row['company_name'];
    htmlBlockTEST();
}

//and in your htmlBlockTEST() function just right this:
function htmlBlockTEST(){
    global $row; ?>
    <h2 class="accName fl"><?php echo $row['company_name']; ?></h2>
    <div class="<?php echo $row['acc_risk']; ?>"> Risk Level. </div>

    <?php
    //ALOT MORE CODE goes here lol.
}
?>
```

You have some more options of course.

Comment: Third option might be to give all results to htmlBlockTEST($all);

Comment: Hello Reza. In short, it worked. I had to make some minor changes but overall it works. When i added the "global" to "$row" outside the function only, it didnt work, i removed it and placed it inside the function and it now all works. What i dont understand is the how or why. I could understand it working as a global outside the function but inside it?....im lost. Can you help me understand? Thanks.

Comment: You can see that I've written `global $row;` in two places above. The first one above the while loop is not necessary only if it is not inside any function; but you can declare global here having no problem. Now the 2nd one is must, because it is necessary to let the system know that it is/may defined outside of this function and you can use it; But if you change the value of this inside variable, it will also change/update for the whole system; So, in short, 1st one is optional/mendatory depends on its declaring place, but the 2nd one is must.